# How do I change the tab content color for each pill (tab) in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav-pills

I have set up a Bootstrap tab/pills nav thing. I have 3 tabs: "adopt", "donate" and join. I want it so that the content background matches the color of the active tab.

```
<div id="exTab1" class="container"> 

  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a  class="adopt-tab" href="#1a" data-toggle="tab">ADOPT</a></li>
    <li><a class="donate-tab" href="#2a" data-toggle="tab">DONATE</a></li>
    <li><a class="join-tab" href="#3a" data-toggle="tab">JOIN</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

So far I have managed to set it so that each pill has a different color, and the first tab's content matches the color of the pill. However, the other tab's content are currently using the same color...

```
#exTab1 .tab-content {
  color : white;
  padding : 5px 15px;
  background-color: #EF476F;
}
```

I assume I have to link it to the ID (#1a, #2a, #3a) but I haven't found a way for each tab to have a different color.

Here is a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/tknipe/pen/NMjEYd) which hopefully explains what i mean.

Comment: this is fixed now but side question, why does the color of the tab header change when clicking off the div? only seems to happen on 'donate' and 'join' tabs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers shouldn't be used as the first char for `id=""` attributes, therefore the `#exTab1 .tab-content > #2a` CSS selector isn't working. However, you can select the tabs id's in CSS like this...

https://www.codeply.com/go/uhGzMhFlQs

```
#exTab1 .tab-content > [id='1a']  {
    background-color: #EF476F;
}

#exTab1 .tab-content > [id='2a']  {
    background-color: #FF6663;
}

#exTab1 .tab-content > [id='3a']  {
    background-color: #FFD166;
}
```

**Update for Bootstrap 4**

Here is a working [example for Bootstrap 4](https://www.codeply.com/go/tNM3S2plFu). The `.active` class should now be placed on the `nav-link` and CSS updated accordingly. Also, it's not good practice the give elements `id=` that start with numbers (1a, 2a, 3a, etc...). Consider renaming the tabs to `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, etc...

[Updated for Bootstrap 4.3.1 + Fill height](https://www.codeply.com/go/o8pDZq0Xoo)

Comment: this works perfectly, and thanks for the tip about IDs :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, each tab should have a different color. So each `tab-pane` has a specific class to set specific color for tab content. Add this code to your CSS.

```
/** this changes needs in you existing CSS **/

#exTab1 .tab-content {
  color : white;
  padding : 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/*New css to add*/

.tab-pane.adopt-tab {
  background-color: #EF476F;
}
.tab-pane.donate-tab {
  background: #FF6663;
}
.tab-pane.join-tab {
  background-color: #FFD166;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the background-color fix, you'll need to adjust the CSS you use for `.tab-content` as well. Your original code set the background color on the parent div which causes problems when changing the background on the children (i.e. the tab-panes).

```
.container {
  margin-top: 32px;
}


/* tab content */
#exTab1 .tab-content {
  color : white;
}
.tab-pane {
  padding : 5px 15px;
  background-color: #EF476F;
}
/* my attempt at individual tab styling */
#exTab1 .tab-content > #2a {
    background-color: #FF6663;
}



/* pills styling */
#exTab1 .nav-pills > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
div#exTab1.container {
    padding-bottom: 64px;
}
li.active {
    background: #E9C46A;
}
.nav-pills > li > a.adopt-tab {
    color: #EF476F;
    border: none;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a.adopt-tab {
    background-color: #EF476F;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
.nav-pills > li > a.donate-tab {
    color: #FF6663;
    border: none;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a.donate-tab, .tab-pane.donate-tab {
    background-color: #FF6663;
    border: none;
}
.nav-pills > li > a.join-tab {
    color: #FFD166;
    border: none;
}
.nav-pills > li.active > a.join-tab, .tab-pane.join-tab {
    background-color: #FFD166;
    border: none;
}





/*form stuff*/
form {
    padding: 32px;
}
label {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
}
input {
    border: none;
}
.input-group input {
    height: 40px;
}
.form-group select {
    height: 40px;
}
span.input-group-addon {
    border: none;
}
select {
    border: none;
}
.butn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 43.6px;
    height: 40px;
    background: none;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;

}
```

Comment: you were right about moving the padding to the '.tab-pane' div but as zim said I had to change the ID to make it work. Thanks for your help :)